# how can i generate same output with jaspyt encrypt

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

basically what i do is

```
BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
textEncryptor.setPassword(passphrase);
return textEncryptor.encrypt(clearText);
```

and lets say; for ABC as input, this generates
one time XYZ and the other time QWE as output. I think its because of its random salt generation or something else.

so my question is: how can i generate same encryped output for a given
input string every time encrypt method is called.

thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to generate the same output?

Comment: I am masking a tabular data. So the records have to be consistent

Comment: I don't understand how that's related. First of all, why are you displaying the encrypted text in a table? Second, what is a record? Third, consistent how?

Comment: Well records are table rows. Imagine 3 rows with same phone no. After encryption i shouldnot see the real phone numbers but i must see that these three rows have same phone number.

Comment: Why are you encrypting it? When you encrypt something, you don't want anyone to know what the underlying value is. The way you're describing your issue, you very much want to know that they are the same. Encryption doesn't seem like the right tool for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ZeroSaltGenerator.

```
PooledPBEStringEncryptor entextEncryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
entextEncryptor.setSaltGenerator(new ZeroSaltGenerator());
```